# Inverse of first-order and third-order polynomial functions

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, inverse, inverse-function

Consider the real-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=ax+b$. Assume that $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. The function $f$ is bijective and is invertible (it also satisfies the horizontal/vertical tests). Thus, $f$ has an inverse function.

First, we write $y=ax+b$.

Now, suppose the inverse is $x=cy+d$.

Next, substitute $x=cy+d$ into $y=ax+b$ yields $$x=c(ax+b)+d=acx+bc+d.$$

Then, we rewrite the above equation and so $x(ac-1)+bc+d=0$.

Hence, we have $ac-1=0$, so $c=1/a$ and $bc+d=0$, so $-bc=0$ or $d=-b/a$.

In conclusion, the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{a}x-\frac{b}{a}$.

We can verify like $f^{-1}(f(x))=\frac{1}{a}(ax+b)-\frac{b}{a}=x$ for all $x$.

Are there any issues with what I have written above? Is the proof rigorous? Do I abuse any math notion?

Would the above method work for finding the inverse function of a cubic polynomial function, say $f(x)=y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$? For example, assuming that $x=\alpha y^3+\beta y^2+\gamma y+\delta$ is the inverse and substituting into $f(x)$?

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: The linear function $ax+b$ is bijective iff $a \neq 0$. Obviously the inverse you obtained does not make sense when $a=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linear case, the writing and math are both good. Note that how much should be included depends upon your goal as a writer. If your goal is to demonstrate not only what the answer is but how you arrived at that answer, then everything you've written is great to keep. However, if your goal is to give the answer, then everything from "First, we write ..." to "... In conclusion" can be omitted: the statement of what the inverse function is, and the verification that it is the inverse function, is all that is needed.

The cubic case will be substantially more difficult, in part because not all cubic functions are invertible: consider $f(x) = x^3 - x$. Even for a cubic function that is invertible, such as $g(x) = x^3 + x$, the formula for the inverse will be complicated: just solving $g(x) = 1$ by itself is already quite complicated. And these cubics don't even have quadratic terms yet....

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have a quick question: it seems to me that it's wrong to assume that the inverse function, if it exists, of a cubic polynomial function has a functional form of a cubic polynomial function? This seems wrong to me.

Comment: The inverse of a cubic is not going to be a cubic again. (The composition of two cubic polynomials is a degree-$9$ polynomial.) For example, the inverse function of $f(x)=x^3$ is $f^{-1}(x)=x^{1/3}$. In general, a function and its inverse will be quite different functions (think of $e^x$ and $\ln x$ for example). Linear functions are very special in this regard.